Converting py to exe - module not found PySide6
I try to convert my .py scripts (using PySide6 to create an interface - the script is working great on VisualStudioCode) in an .exe using auto_py_to_exe and because it didn't work multiple times I tried with PyInstaller via GitBash.
The following message appears when I click on the .exe file:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nombre_mystere.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6'

I tried to put the environment in which I installed PySide6 in the "additional Files" on auto_py_to_exe and I still have the same message when I try.
I tried to install Python 3.8 because it seems that with PySide2 the issue isn't there but my computer said I had a newer version of Python and stopped the installation on its own.
Putting PySide6 in hidden import didn't work either on auto_py_to_exe.
Command on auto_py_to_exe :
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --hidden-import "PySide6"  "C:\Users\Broua\Desktop\Python\Cours\Nombre_mystere\nombre_mystere.py"
I also tried to type : $ pip install requests on GitBash
What could I do?
